# Pasting copied text to vim encoding issue

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I copy some russian text from browser to vim then in insert mode pasting it via CTRL-R + * and getting a whole bunch of unreadable characters. I tried to set some fileencoding encoding and termencoding to utf-8 but that did not work.

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04
I use standard bash terminal
The problem appears only in non-gui vim version.

these are my .vimrc settings:

- set termencoding=utf-8
- set encoding=utf-8
- set fileencoding=utf-8

Comment: What OS you're using?

Comment: What values of `encoding`, etc. do you use? Does pasting work to GVIM, other applications? Which terminal do you use, and does pasting directly to the shell work? You can't expect help without giving all necessary information.

Comment: @IngoKarkat updated info

Comment: What is your terminal encoding？ try to change it to utf-8.

Comment: @henices user@ubuntu:~$ echo $LANG ->
en_US.UTF-8

Comment: make sure to set your vim to :set paste